# Finding items with attribute value match excluding another value in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have this code :

```
module.exports.MyFunction= async (req, res) => {
  let token = req.body.token;
  let decoded = jwt_decode(token);
  let email = decoded.email;
  let data = req.body;
  let searchUser = data.user;

  try {
    let user = await User.findAll({
      where: {
        [Op.or]: [
          { firstName: searchUser },
          { lastName: searchUser },
          { email: searchUser },
          { publicKey: searchUser },
        ],
      },
      attributes: ["firstName", "lastName", "email", "publicKey", "avatar"],
    }).then((response) => {
      return response;
    });

    res.json({ user });
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ err });
  }
};
```

If I run that code, I get all the users that match with the value passed in searchUser.

What I want to do is to exclude the user object that have a specific email.

For instance, if have multiple users named Michel, I want to get all the users with an email address different of the email variable declared at the top of the function, even if their fisrtName matches.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by doing this :

```
module.exports.MyFunction = async (req, res) => {
  let token = req.body.token;
  let decoded = jwt_decode(token);
  let loggedUserEmail = decoded.email;
  let data = req.body;
  let searchUser = data.user;
  console.log(searchUser);

  try {
    let user = await User.findAll({
      where: {
        [Op.or]: [
          {
            firstName: {
              [Op.startsWith]: searchUser,
            },
          },
          {
            lastName: {
              [Op.startsWith]: searchUser,
            },
          },
          {
            email: {
              [Op.startsWith]: searchUser,
            },
          },
          {
            publicKey: {
              [Op.startsWith]: searchUser,
            },
          },
        ],
        email: {
          [Op.ne]: loggedUserEmail,
        },
       
      },
      attributes: ["firstName", "lastName", "email", "publicKey", "avatar"],
    }).then((response) => {
      return response;
    });

    res.json({ user });
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ err });
  }
};
```